# BigBlueButton: unmet dependencies on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, bigbluebutton

I try to install the last version of BigBlueButton on Ubuntu 10.04.4 LTS

I follow this guide: https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/InstallationUbuntu

On step 5, I have this error message:

```
#apt-get install bigbluebutton
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  bigbluebutton: Depends: bbb-config but it is not going to be installed
E: Broken packages
```

I try to install bbb-config:

```
# apt-get install bbb-config
bbb-config: Depends: `enter code here`bbb-web but it is not going to be installed
```

Then bbb-web

```
# apt-get install bbb-web
bbb-web: Depends: bbb-openoffice-headless but it is not going to be installed
```

Then bbb-openoffice-headless

```
# apt-get install bbb-openoffice-headless
bbb-openoffice-headless: Depends: openoffice.org but it is not going to be installed
```

BBB 0.81 needs LibreOffice, no ? (which is installed)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm one of the developers of BigBlueButton.  Did you already install the stub package for OpenOffice.

BigBlueButton has a dependency on OpenOffice, but the following (taken from the documentation) will install a stub page so it won't pull in the rest of the OpenOffice code.

```
wget http://bigbluebutton.googlecode.com/files/openoffice.org_1.0.4_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i openoffice.org_1.0.4_all.deb
```

Also, can you check if you already have OpenOffice installed.

```
dpkg -l | grep office
```

if so, please remove all the packages, then try following the steps to install libreoffice again.  See https://code.google.com/p/bigbluebutton/wiki/InstallationUbuntu#2._Install_LibreOffice

Regards,... Fred